# Determine media size from ppd file

Tags: printing, postscript, ppd

Ive got Dymo labelwriter 400. It works like a charm with a glabels on ubuntu. I am currently writing software to create automatic labels. for that I need to know the size of the png I want to print.

The paper I use is: Large Address, which is 89x36mm.

When I create and print such an image it is not taking the whole label. It is in fact 2/3 of the label size.

In ppd I found such thing:

`*PageSize w102h252/30321 Large Address: "<</PageSize[102 252]/ImagingBBox null>>setpagedevice"`

I imagine 102 252 is a size. I created such png in gimp, still is too small.

How can I determine what size should the image have to fit the label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size will be in points (72nds of an inch).  For example, 8.5 x 11 (letter) size paper is shown as

```
<</PageSize[ 612 792 ] /ImagingBBox null>>setpagedevice
```

102 = 1.4 inches or 36mm

252 = 2.5 inches or 89mm